# Unity IAP: How Do I Write the Script to Provide the Functionality For Codeless IAP for Current Versions of Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I want to implement Codeless IAP where people can purchase a non-consumable Unity app in the Mac App Store.

I'm using **2017.4.27f**. The documentation for Codeless IAP states that there is not much scripting needed. This is my first time implementing IAP in an app. I don't know all the functions needed to complete a transaction.

The Unity IAP samples provided by Unity were last updated in January 2016 using Unity 5.3.

https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/unity-iap-samples/src/master/

They produce the following scripting errors after I import the assets.

```
Assets/Plugins/UnityPurchasing/script/IAPDemo.cs(20,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Store' does not exist in the namespace `UnityEngine'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Assets/Plugins/UnityPurchasing/script/IAPDemo.cs(630,38): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ILoginListener' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Assets/Plugins/UnityPurchasing/script/IAPDemo.cs(634,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `UserInfo' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Assets/Plugins/UnityPurchasing/script/IAPDemo.cs(647,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `UserInfo' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Here is the script provided by Unity that produced the errors.

https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/unity-iap-samples/src/master/UnityIAPDemo/Assets/Scripts/UnityIAPDemo.cs

If these errors were corrected, can this script be used with current versions of Unity for IAP?

I have searched for several days for more recent information about Unity IAP. I only found videos that showed people how to create a Unity IAP Button and create procedures with Debug.log statements for purchases completed and those that failed. None of them give sample scripts that I can use as a starting point to learn this stuff.

The Unity tutorial that is referenced is also old. I get the same errors.

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/ads-analytics/integrating-unity-iap-your-game

I have not found any questions that cover basic Unity IAP information here or in the Game Development Stack Exchange.

I cannot find a tutorial from Unity that is current.

I'm completely lost after going through the Unity IAP documentation. It assumes that people understand the basics of how IAP transactions work.

Comment: Did you try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfquRI421Ww

Comment: I watched this video yesterday and did the sample. All that is in the script are Debug.log statements. If my memory is correct this video and in other places stated that I have to code something in those methods to process the purchase. Pretty much all the videos were like this one. It does not tell me if I need to code something else to get this working. That is what I don't understand. Is there default code executed behind the scenes since it knows it's a payment button and I want someone to purchase something? That is not in the Unity documentation that I could find.

Comment: I am not sure how you are getting those errors, `ILoginListener` does not appear in the demo script on their bitbucket.

Comment: @Draco18s, I'm brand new to IAP. I don't know enough about this to fix this three year old script. It would be nice if Unity provided an updated version of this. Version 5.3 is a bit old. I'm creating Unity apps for the Mac App Store. The only thing I could find for ILoginListener is with Xiaomi. For something that is supposed to be Codeless IAP, there's sure a lot of code to consider apparently.

Comment: I haven't worked with the builtin "codeless" IAP system, the only time I've worked with IAP was integrating into the Google play store and the Oculus store, and I don't remember much of what I did and no longer have that code.